# Can one specify the thread that the AsyncCallback runs on when using delegate.BeginInvoke?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

From my understanding of .NET, if I use a BackgroundWorker and have an event handler for RunWorkerCompleted, the event handler will run on the same thread in which RunWorkerAsync was called.  If instead I use BeginInvoke on a delegate to run a method asynchronously, and pass an AsyncCallback parameter to BeginInvoke, is there any way I can specify that the callback runs on the same thread that called BeginInvoke -- or for that matter any arbitrary thread?  From my understanding the callback runs on the next available thread from the thread pool. That's fine, but is there a way I can run code in an AsyncCallback on any thread I want?  I do know you can use BeginInvoke on a form or control and make code within the callback run on the thread that created the UI element.  But what about if I want to run code on a non-UI thread with no forms or controls?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On the thread you want to use as the target for your async operation, the [CurrentDispatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.currentdispatcher.aspx) Property is a System.Threading.Dispatcher object that can be used to force a callback to execute on that thread.

This is the base class that the Control class uses to implement BeginInvoke.

Questions have come up about using this with Windows forms.  I don't think this will be a problem, although if you have a form, then form.BeginInvoke is a better choice. It appears that both the form and WPF use the same base class for handling invoke. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext.aspx

Comment: System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher is WPF specific and doesn't have anything to do with the thread where the AsyncCallback of a Delegate.BeginInvoke is called.

Comment: @Jeff: it provides an alternate BeginInvoke method to allow targeting of the callback.  As far as I can tell, this is what he really wants and just muddled his terminology while asking the question.

Comment: @John:  Yes I probably did muddle my terminology.  I am going to edit my question.  I think your answer answers my question.  If I want to execute code in a callback on a specific thread, I can pass along to it the Dispatcher of the thread and call BeginInvoke on it.  Thanks.

Comment: @John: it appears you're referring to `System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher`, which appears to be specific to WPF. Can it be used with Windows Forms?

Comment: The Dispatcher is available in .NET 3

Comment: @John: For a thread that has a Windows Form, you can use Form.BeginInvoke instead. (although I suspect that CurrentDispatcher on a Windows Forms owning thread will give you the same object that Form.BeginInvoke uses, the documentation implies this).

Comment: @John: a citation, or some research using Reflector, would be more valuable than a belief that they are the same.

Comment: @John: check the link I appended.  They are derived from the same base class.

Comment: `System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherSynchronizationContext` is derived from `System.Threading.SynchronizationContext. This does not necessarily imply that `System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher` uses `DispatcherSynchronizationContext`.

Answer (score 5):

Delegate.BeginInvoke will always execute the delegate in the ThreadPool and the AsyncCallback is called on the same thread that executed the delegate.

Your only choice is to re-invoke the callback on your specific thread:

```
AsyncCallback = delegate (IAsyncResult ar)
{
    wathever.BeginInvoke(delegate
    {
        // Do your stuff...
    };
};
```

Comment: Do you mean that the AsyncCallback is called on the same thread that called BeginInvoke?  This seems contrary to what I understand from the MSDN documentation article entitled "Calling Synchronous Methods Asynchronously" (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e08f6yc.aspx) where it says "If the thread that initiates the asynchronous call does not need to be the thread that processes the results, you can execute a callback method when the call completes."

Comment: No, I meant that when you call Delegate.BeginInvoke from thread A, this delegate is executed on a thread B in the ThreadPool and then the AsyncCallback is called on thread B.

Comment: True.  I just verified it.  I don't think they make that clear in the MSDN documentation.

Answer (score 0):

The thread will always be a thread pool thread, and will never be a UI thread.

BTW, C# has no `BackgroundWorker` class. .NET does.

Comment: Thanks.  I didn't mean to imply BackgroundWorker was C# specific.  I took that out.

Answer (score 0):

I did a search and I ended up on [Jon Skeet's site](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/threads/threadpool.shtml). It is very informative about how the threading works with asynchronous delegates and callbacks. I would highly recommend this read.